# Number of conjugacy classes for the modular group

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, unimodular-matrices

What is the number $N$ of conjugacy classes for the modular group (integer matrices with determinant one), corresponding to each trace T? Is there a reasonably closed formula that would give such number as $N = f(T)$?

Comment: Yes, there is a formula related to the class numbers of real quadratic number fields, see [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X85900496/pdf?md5=eeba1b8e710b3b2c4025f602042235db&pid=1-s2.0-0022314X85900496-main.pdf) by Charles Traina. For example, all matrices of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with trace $3$ are conjugated over $\mathbb{Z}$, because the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that it was linked with class numbers. That shows it is not going to be as easy as I hoped...

Comment: I followed the lead given in the paper (Olga Taussky's theorem) and discovered that plenty of work on this problem was also done by Svetlana Katok (for instance: "Coding of closed geodesics after Gauss and Morse" in Geometriae Dedicata 63 (2), 123-145)